# MySql Error 1064 I don't know what I've done wrong

Tags: mysql

Sorry, I know that there are very similar questions out there, but I just dont get what I've done wrong here.

The code

```
 CREATE TABLE Kontakte 
( 
Vorname varchar(255), 
Nachname varchar(255), 
Alter varchar(255), 
Geburtsdatum DATE, 
Adresse varchar(255), 
Ort varchar(255), 
Nummer varchar(255),
NummerHaus varchar(255), 
Email varchar(255), 
Anmerkung TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 
);
```

gives this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Alter varchar(255), Geburtsdatum DATE, Adresse varchar(255), Ort varchar(255), N' at line 1

Can somebody please help me!

Comment: The syntax highlighting makes your error obvious

Comment: Remove Alter varchar(255) from ur code